How to prove that $A_n=f^{-1}(B)$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B} ([0,1])$
Let $\{A_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a family of subsets of $X$, and $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$, and define
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n}I_{A_n}$$
Where $I_{A_n}$ is the indicator function of $A_n$. I am trying to prove that $A_n=f^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel set $B$. For $A_1$ is not problematic to see that $A_1=f^{-1}([1/3,2/3])$, while for $n\ge 2$ my conjecture is that
$$A_n=f^{-1}\left(\left[\frac{1}{3^n},\frac{2}{3^n}\right]\cup \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{3^n},\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{2}{3^n}\right]\right).$$
I'm trying to prove this by showing that $A_n\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ and then that $A_n^c\subseteq f^{-1}(B^c)=f^{-1}(B)^c$, that gives the equality. For the first part I supposed that $x\in A_n$ and divided by cases: it is pretty long but it seems to work. The problem is that I'm blocked at the second part: I supposed that $x\notin A_n$ and tried to prove that $f(x)\in B^c$, but this doesn't seem to work.
Since now I'm stuck, I'm starting to think that my conjecture is wrong, so what I'm asking is:

Is the conjecture right or wrong?
If it's wrong, what is the correct $B$ that I'm looking for?
Is there a clever and fastest way to prove the equality than going case by case?


I may be missing something, but I think that, for all $x \in X$, $f(x) \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$.

Your conjecture isn't quite right. Take $n=3$ for example. If $x\in A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3$ and $x\notin A_k$ for $k > 3$, then $f(x) = \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 9+ \frac 1 {27} = \frac{13}{27}$. But $\frac{13}{27}$ isn't in the set you defined. You need to think about all possible values of $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 3^{-k} I_{A_k}$ when defining your set $B$. What might be easier is to define the sets of points implicitly. That is, take $$ H_n = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k 3^{k-1} : a_k \in \{0,1\}\right\} $$ to be the set of all possible values of the head of the summation. Then your set $$ B_n = \bigcup_{x\in H_n} [x + 1/3^n, x+ 2/3^n)$$ should give you $f^{-1}(B_n) = A_n$.
EDIT: I'll try to expand some points that I didn't discuss in my original answer. Applying a ternary expansion to the numbers could be useful in showing the answer, but I'm not sure if that is assuming too much. To show $f(A_n) \subset B_n$, note that for $x\in A_n$ we hvae $$ f(x) = \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^{-k} 1_{A_k}\right)}_{\in H_n} + 3^{-n}  + \underbrace{\left( \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 3^{-n} 1_{A_k}\right)}_{< 1/3^n}$$ and so $f(x) \in B_n$. For the other direction, it is useful to note that $|x-y| \geq \frac1{3^{n-1}}$ for distinct $x,y\in H_n$. So for $x\in A_n^c$, $$f(x) = \underbrace{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}3^{-k} 1_{A_k}\right)}_{\in H_n} + \underbrace{\left( \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty 3^{-n} 1_{A_k}\right)}_{< 1/3^n} \in [y, y + 1/3^n)$$ where $y$ is the head of the summation. Clearly $[y,y+1/3^n)$ is disjoint from $[y+1/3^n, y + 2/3^n)$. Also for any $z\in H_n$, $[z + 1/3^n, z+ 2/3^n)$ must be disjoint from $[y,y+1/3^n)$ since $|z-y| \geq 1/3^{n-1}.$ Thus $f(x) \notin B_n$

@LuigiTraino I expanded my answer to address the rest of the proof.
